# How to run certain OneDrive account at start-up (not all)?

Tags: microsoft-office, onedrive

I have two OD accounts on my device. At the start-up OneDrive starts synchronization for all accounts. I want to choose only one. Is there any way besides disconnecting second account?

EDIT: The second account is pretty large - around 700 GB - and not everything has been downloaded yet. OD start-up for this account causes 100% disk usage which makes my computer a zombie. However, I would like to run this OD when needed (and not connect-disconnect this account each time).

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser! What's the underlying issue you're trying to solve? *Why* do you wan't to sync only one account and not the other, without disconnecting the other account? This can help others to come up with solution that actually solves your issue.

Comment: Please check my edit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This seems like a perfect use case for [OneDrive Files On-Demand](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/save-disk-space-with-onedrive-files-on-demand-for-windows-10-0e6860d3-d9f3-4971-b321-7092438fb38e):

> OneDrive Files On-Demand helps you access all your cloud storage in OneDrive without having to download all of them and use file storage space on your Windows device.

To turn on this feature you can follow the steps in the previously linked help page, which are:

> 2. Select the white or blue OneDrive cloud icon in the Windows taskbar notification area.
> 3. Select OneDrive Help and Settings icon Help & Settings > Settings.
> 4. On the Settings tab, select the Save space and download files as you use them box.

Comment: I know my way of thinking seems to be irrational but I think I'm asking for something probably useful. This is not exactly what I'm looking for. Let's assume that everything in my edit is irrelevant. I'm asking if there's any way to choose exact accounts to synchronize on start-up (without disconnecting them from device)?

Comment: I don't think it's irrelevant, it helps create a question without an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/222653).
With the above "files on-demand" functionality it seems to me you could exactly do what you request: for the second account you set the files on-demand feature -> nothing is synced on startup. If you want to sync, you click the folder of the second account and mark it as "always available" -> syncing is now being done based on your request. Want to stop syncing? Right click the folder and mark it as "Available online" (or something along those lines).

Comment: I see your point and agree. Thanks for help! :)